# Spark streaming append output mode with trigger once

Tags: apache-spark, apache-kafka, spark-streaming, spark-structured-streaming

I try to use Spark streaming (2.2.0) with Kafka input and such configuration:

- Watermarking and aggregation
- Windowing
- Output mode: OutputMode.Append()
- Trigger mode: Trigger.Once()

But I have no output (neither in kafka nor in console).
Launching the application multiple times does not work either.

When I use OutputMode.Complete() or Trigger.ProcessingTime(0L), it works. But unfortunately, this is not my need.

Is **append** mode supported with trigger **once** ?

Here is a minimal application to reproduce the issue.
[Gist](https://gist.github.com/mprevel/84b86e6db3488e9045fbdcb61508a51e)

```scala
case class Model(valueForGroupBy: Int, time: Timestamp)

object Application {

  val appName = "sample"

//  val outputMode: OutputMode = OutputMode.Complete() // OK
  val outputMode: OutputMode = OutputMode.Append() // KO with trigger once

  val triggerMode: Trigger = Trigger.Once()

  val delayThreshold: FiniteDuration = 1.minute // watermarking wait for late

  val duration : FiniteDuration = 1.minute // window duration and slide

  val topic = "SAMPLE_TOPIC"
  val bootstrapServers = "127.0.0.1:9092"


  type KafkaKV = (String, String)

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {

    val spark: SparkSession = SparkSession
      .builder
      .appName(appName)
      .getOrCreate()

    import org.apache.spark.sql._
    import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
    import spark.implicits._

    val streamReader: DataStreamReader = spark.readStream
      .format("kafka")
      .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", bootstrapServers)
      .option("subscribe", topic)
      .option("startingOffsets", "earliest")
      .option("failOnDataLoss", "false")

    val df: DataFrame = streamReader.load()

    val ds: Dataset[Model] = df.selectExpr("CAST(key AS STRING)", "CAST(value AS STRING)").as[KafkaKV]
      .select(from_json($"value", Encoders.product[Model].schema).as("json"))
      .select($"json.*")
      .as[Model]

    val groupByColumns = Seq(
      window(new Column("time"), windowDuration = duration.toString, slideDuration = duration.toString),
      new Column("valueForGroupBy")
    )

    val agg = ds
      .withWatermark("time", delayThreshold.toString)
      .groupBy(groupByColumns: _*)
      .count()

    val streamWriter = agg
      .selectExpr(s"CAST(valueForGroupBy AS STRING) AS key", "to_json(struct(*)) AS value")
      .writeStream
      .trigger(triggerMode)
      .outputMode(outputMode)
      .format("console")
      .option("truncate", value = false)

    val streamingQuery = streamWriter.start()

    streamingQuery.awaitTermination()

  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a known BUG of Spark.

In actual implementation, watermark is persisted in the following batch. As there is no following batch in trigger once, the watermak is never persisted.

A ticket exists in Spark bugtracker : https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-24699

Answer (score 0):

Append mode with Trigger Once is not supported.

It is a Spark known bug: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-24699

Comment: This is now supported